# Hadoop "WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes"

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop in Windows 11.

Executing command `hdfs namenode -format` emits the following message:

```
    2022-05-17 18:30:32,792 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
    2022-05-17 18:30:33,922 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    2022-05-17 18:30:36,240 INFO common.Util: Assuming 'file' scheme for path /hadoop/data/namenode in configuration.
    2022-05-17 18:30:36,254 INFO common.Util: Assuming 'file' scheme for path /hadoop/data/namenode in configuration.
   
    2022-05-17 18:30:45,106 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: There's no error here - that WARN is common and doesn't mean anything is wrong.

Comment: In the end it SHUTDOWN and I can't access the system hadoop. I don’t know what happened because I tried commands with path data and namenode, but didn't create any information in the file.

Comment: You've cut off the `SHUTDOWN_MSG`, so we don't know what the real issue might be, but also Windows isn't a preferred Hadoop environment. You could try WSL2 instead

Comment: That message is normal. There is nothing weird happening here. Unless there are some error logs above. The format was successful. You just need to shoot a start namenode command now...